# How can i make this code more optimized - How can i replace the forloop.?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

How can I improve the performance if this Code snippet.

```
bool OrSetFinalResult =true;
string OrSet = "(1&1)|0";
string[] AndSets = OrSet.Split('&');
foreach (string AndSet in AndSets)
{
    if (AndSet == "0")
    {
        // A single "false" statement makes the entire And statement FALSE
        OrSetFinalResult = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to remove the ForEach loop with any of the `LINQ` expressions ?

Comment: Can you not use `OrSet.Contains("0")` ?

Comment: So what should the output be if `OrSet = "1|0&1|0"` for example?

Comment: Am I wrong or after split you will have `"(1"` and `"1)|0"` strings and your if statement will be always false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like:

```
if (AndSets.Contains("0"))
{
    OrSetFinalResult = false;
}
```

No need for LINQ at all. It'll still loop internally of course, but it's still a lot simpler.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you could also use:

```
OrSetFinalResult = OrSetFinalResult && !OrSet.Split('&').Contains("0");
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `OrSetFinalResult = AndSets.Contains("0");`?

Comment: @norlando: That was my first answer (well, inverted), but not necessarily. Suppose `OrSetFinalResult` is *already* false, but there aren't any "0" elements in there. We don't necessarily want to set it to true.

Comment: `OrSetFinalResult = OrSetFinalResult && !OrSet.Split('&').Contains("0")` combines @norlando's approach with your concern that `OrSetFinalResult` could already be false, with the added benefit of skipping the whole thing in that case.

Comment: Oops looks like I forgot to add `!` to the check.

Comment: but... this is not making much Improvement... only a slight improvement is there

Comment: @Sreekumar: Well I did *say* it's just changing the code, not the work that it does. Fundamentally it's hard to see how it could possibly avoid looping...

Answer (score 2):

You don't include the definition of `OrSetFinalResult` so the fastest I can think of would be:

```
OrSetFinalResult = OrSetFinalResult && !OrSet.Split('&').Contains("0");
```

Since this skips the whole thing if it's already false anyway.

More generally, the best you can do with any search is:

1. If the collection is hashed based on the feature you are searching for (in this case, on the string itself) then O(1).
2. If the collection is sorted based on the feature you are searching for, then O(log n).
3. If the collection is not sorted, then O(n).

There are intermediate cases. E.g. if I want to find a particular X-Y coordinate from a set of coordinates only sorted on the X coordinate then it is O(√n log √n) assuming a reasonably even distribution.

In this case, we have the O(n) case.

Putting the values into a `HashSet<string>` would make this search O(1), but doing so is an O(n) operation in itself (and with higher constant effects). Therefore it would be a saving if you were going to search multiple times, but not if you were only going to search once.

Comment: `OrSetFinalResult` is a boolean variable , I have edited that, see the EDIT.

Comment: Then I'd place its definition after that of OrSet and have it as `bool OrSetFinalResult = !OrSet.Split('&').Contains("0");`. What I've said about the more general problem of searching still applies.

Comment: but... this is not making much Improvement... only a slight improvement is there

Comment: Yep. O(n) is the best you can do for the reasons given. You could get an improvement with `OrSet.Contains("0")`  or even `OrSet.Contains('0') since it's one-char long, but I assume that the `Split` in your code isn't how the real code would get it's values. It's still O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Any operator in Linq.

```
string OrSet = "(1&1)|0";
string[] AndSets = OrSet.Split('&');
OrSetFinalResult = !AndSets.Any(x => x == "0");
```

Comment: but... this is not making much Improvement... only a slight improvement is there

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `any` operator in linq which would produce similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing string parsing with LINQ is the opposite of optimization in most cases (assuming you meant runtime optimization).

I'm guessing an linear tokenizer will be much much faster. Perhaps I'll do a sample benchmark (if I find time)

Answer (score 0):

```
string OrSet = "(1&1)|0";
bool OrSetFinalResult = true;
    if (OrSet.Contains("0"))
    {
        // A single "false" statement makes the entire And statement FALSE
        OrSetFinalResult = false;

    }
```

This will give you same result.

Comment: but... this is not making much Improvement... only a slight improvement is there

Comment: it will consumes much less memory than you maintain